# Windows service with WCF programmatically created: how to expose it with Per-Call InstanceContextMode?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

my application is composed by a lot of different windows service. Each of them creates programmatically a WCF service. I tried to configure my service with a "per-call" instancecontextmode but it seems to process one request at time.

What should I do? 
The class implementing the service interface is decorated with this attribute:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
```

While the service is instantiated like this:

```
ServiceHost _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(IMultiMarketBatchNotification));
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMultiMarketBatchNotification), binding, myAddress);
```

where:

- IMultiMarketBatchNotification is  the service interface
- binding is the instance of the binding (NetTcpBinding)
- myAddress is a string containing the service url (like net.tcp://...)

Isn't that enough?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 4):

You need to add those lines of code after instating your `ServiceHost`, but before opening it:

```
// look for the "ServiceBehavior" 
ServiceBehaviorAttribute srvBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();

if (srvBehavior == null)
{
   // if we didn't find the service behavior - create one and add it to the list of behaviors
   srvBehavior = new ServiceBehaviorAttribute();
   srvBehavior.InstanceContextMode == InstanceContextMode.PerCall;
   host.Description.Behaviors.Add(srvBehavior);
}
else
{
   // if we found it - make sure the InstanceContextMode is set up properly
   srvBehavior.InstanceContextMode == InstanceContextMode.PerCall;
}
```

That should do it.

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your reply. I didnt try it because the missing thing was about the CoucurrencyMode. Adding that, my service started becoming multithreaded! Thank you anyway for your help!